# Excel - How to separate multiple data in one row (that is separated by a comma) into different rows and keep the unique value?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Do you know of any command that can turn this,

[image]

Into this,

[image]

Comment: The easiest way is to use `TextToColumns`, separated by `,`, and then delete the columns you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

Use Text To Columns to split the cells into multiple columns, then use the Unpivot feature in the Power Query editor to make the "unpivotted" (denormalised) table you asked for.

Power Query is complex, but in this case it is very simple to do. Just follow the instructions here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2015/12/15/learn-how-to-unpivot-static-tables-in-excel-2016/ (also works in Excel-365)

Answer (score 0):

Just 3 steps.
[Split by characters tool](https://www.ablebits.com/excel-clean-cells/index.php?tool=SplitText) will split the values from B2:B4 to 9 cells C2:C10. Then the [Fill Blank Cells tool](https://www.ablebits.com/excel-fill-blank-cells/index.php) will fill the empty values in column A. Delete column B and you will get the desired result. It is available as a part of our Ultimate Suite for Excel that you can install in a trial mode and check how it works for free.

Answer (score 0):

Select the Range- go to **Data**- **From Table/Range**- open **PowerQuery editor**:

[image]

Select the **ID column**- go to **Home**- **Split Column: by Delimiter**- select **OK**:

[image]

Select **ID.1, ID.2, ID.3 columns**- go to **Transform**- **Unpivot Columns**:

[image]

Remove Attribute column- **Close and Load**:

[image]

[image]